# My stop button is pausing all the thread instead of pausing specific thread

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I have `Class1[] QR;` defined in my `Class2.java`

Where Class1 is a different class which extends `Task<Integer>` and I am doing some stuff over there.

I have following variables defined inside Class2 as follows:

```
 public class Class2 implements Initializable {

private ProgressBar[] prog_QR;
private Label[] lab_QR;
public Button[] stop_QR;
public Class1[] QR;
public boolean RunningQRState;
ExecutorService QueueReaderExecutorService;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) 
{
    QR = new ResultsReader[10];

    prog_QR = new ProgressBar[10];
    lab_QR = new Label[10];
    stop_QR = new Button[10];

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        prog_QR[i] = new ProgressBar();
        stop_QR[i] = new Button();
        stop_QR[i].setText("Stop");

        lab_QR[i] = new Label("Thread " + i);

    // more stuff   
    }
    @FXML
   private void act_Start(ActionEvent event) 
   {

     if(RunningQRState)
     {

     RunningQRState = false;
     }
     else
     {

     RunningQRState = true;

     // Set up thread pool
        QueueReaderExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            QR[i] = new Class1(i);

            prog_QR[i].progressProperty().bind(QR[i].progressProperty());
            lab_QR[i].textProperty().bind(QR[i].messageProperty());
            //stop_QR[i].textProperty().bind(QR[i].messageProperty());// By AK

             stop_QR[i].setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
              {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event)
                  {
                        System.out.println("Stop Button number Clicked");

                        try
                             {
                                Thread.sleep(5000);
                                }
                      catch (InterruptedException interrupted)
                         {
                            if (isCancelled())
                            {
                                System.out.println("QRC Cancelled");
                             }
                        }
                   }

                private boolean isCancelled() {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                }
            });

            //QR[i].setQDVC(this);

            QueueReaderExecutorService.execute(QR[i]);
        }
    }
```

So I see 10 "Stop" button next to my progress bar. So, once I start the application, all threads start running.

My **GOAL** is to stop a specific thread when a user click on it.For that I have put a sleep of 5 sec. But the problem is that, when I click on any of the STOP button, it 
        puts all the threads into sleep mode.

Please let me know what am I doing wrong here.

2. How should I go about terminating a specific thread instead of putting it in sleep mode?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. What kind of work your Task implementation do? Please, provide more code or information.
2. How about using [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)? You can obtain it through ExecutorService **submit(task)** method invocation instead of **execute(task)** which doesn't provide task completion contract. Future may cancel underlying task in any time. I think it what you're searching for. Hope this helps.